# subdividing an ansible role for certain cluster roles

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory like this (`inventory`):

```
[worker_nodes]
ubuntuw01
ubuntuw02
ubuntuw03
ubuntuw04
[worker_nodes:vars]
kube_role="worker"

[controlplane_nodes]
ubuntuc01
ubuntuc02
[controlplane_nodes:vars]
kube_role="controlplane"

[etcd_nodes]
ubuntue01
ubuntue02
ubuntue03
[etcd_nodes:vars]
kube_role="etcd"
```

For which I would like to apply a role like this (`myplay.yml`):

```
---

- name: tasks for kube cluster
  hosts: all
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - os_patching
```

My `roles/os_patching/tasks/main.yml` looks like this:

```
---

  - name: "Update etc nodes"
    import_tasks: etcd.yml
    when: kube_role == "etcd"

  - name: "Update controlplane nodes"
    import_tasks: controlplane.yml
    when: kube_role == "controlplane"


  - name: "Update worker nodes"
    import_tasks: worker.yml
    when: kube_role == "worker"
```

When I run ansible like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -b myplay.yml
```

I am getting

```
TASK [<various task names>] ***************************************************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu02]
```

for most tasks except for trivial ones like `Gathering Facts`.
I guess my `when` clause is not working as expected, however I am a bit lost on why this is. What am I doing wrong?

An alternative approach would be to define separate roles, however the node types share tasks, so I
thought this would be a good idea. Also, its a cluster so I would like to have the complete view of how the cluster is getting patched in one role. Maybe that is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be rather simple, I do not even need to define any special variables. My inventory:

```
[worker_nodes]
ubuntuw01
ubuntuw02
ubuntuw03
ubuntuw04

[controlplane_nodes]
ubuntuc01
ubuntuc02

[etcd_nodes]
ubuntue01
ubuntue02
ubuntue03
```

And my `main.yml`:

```
---

  - name: "Update etcd nodes"
    import_tasks: etcd.yml
    when: "'etcd_nodes' in group_names"

  - name: "Update controlplane nodes"
    import_tasks: controlplane.yml
    when: "'controlplane_nodes' in group_names"

  - name: "Update worker nodes"
    import_tasks: worker.yml
    when: "'worker_nodes' in group_names"
```

So basically I am checking for a group name that a particular node is in in the `when` clause.